# I'm trying to use a function to pre-load the data of my CKEEditor using React

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

This is my code:

```
  useLayoutEffect (() => {
      const queryString = window.location.search;
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
      const idBorrador = urlParams.get('tipo');
      if (idBorrador) {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/getReport?id=${idBorrador}`);
  
            document.getElementById("tipo").value = response.data.tipo;
            document.getElementById("aux").value= response.data.nota;
    
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data for the draft:', error);
          }
        };
  
        fetchData(); // Call the async function
      }
    }, []);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      async function seteo() {
        try {
       editor.setData(document.getElementById("aux").value);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        }
      }
      
      seteo()
   }, []);
```

The idea being that LayoutEffect brings data from a database. Since it seems CKEditor wasn't loaded by the time I called it, I decided to store the value of response.data.nota in a hidden input called aux.

I tried two things. Firstly, use useEffect with the empty [] to call editor.setData, but I'm getting the 'editor not defined' error. I also tried

```
  <CKEditor
          editor={ClassicEditor}

          id="cuerpo"
          data={document.getElementById("aux").value}
          name="cuerpo"
          onReady={(editor) => {
```

and it didn't work either. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to fetch data in `useLayoutEffect` because it runs synchronously.

I don't have the full context on why you want to pre-load data?

But the way to solve this would be to simply render the component somewhere in your top level component tree and do a `useEffect` fetch as usual, so when the user reaches your component/page, the data will be already loaded for them.